# Prove that ${p(x)\over q(x)}=\sum_{i=1} ^{\deg q} {p(\alpha_i)\over q(\alpha_i)(x-\alpha_i)}$

Tags: polynomials

Prove that $\frac {p(x)} {q(x)} = \sum \limits _{i=1} ^{\deg q} \frac {p(\alpha_i)} {q(\alpha_i) (x-\alpha_i)}$ where $\deg q > \deg p$ and $\{\alpha_i\} _{i = 1, \dots, \deg q}$ are roots of $q$.

I tried this way: $f'(x) = \sum \limits _i \frac {f(x)} {(x-\alpha_i)}$
but I couldn't reach the final step. I think that by taking a general polynomial, I may prove the result or by induction. But this will be quite lengthy.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @Qwerty, rather than do edits like this one, better not do them at all. Why did you leave *"I varies from 1 to n, n is degree of q(x)>degree of p(x),α are roots of q(x)"* in the title, instead of replacing it with more appropriate formulae and MathJax code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $q(x)$, one can see that this formula is a way of re-writing Lagrange interpolation formula to $p(x)$ at abscissas $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ... \alpha_n$, as shown in [this reference](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~math211/m211oh/m211oh51.pdf)